# Okta Client Credentials Access Token Issue

Tags: java, spring, okta

When i am trying to get access token through client credentials flow in okta ,i have got sucessfully,but by using that access token i am not able to fetch any user details.Like the code below

```
token.getTokenAttributes().get("uid").toString();
```

The above token object is jwtAuthenticationToken Which is used in web application.

i am using spring-boot okta

Answer (score 0):

The Client Credentials flow is intended for server-side (confidential) client applications with no end user, which normally describes machine-to-machine communication.

It wouldn't have user context and it won’t have a user tied to the access token.

Comment: Thanks ...but is there any other way through which i can get access token on user basis for machine to machine communication.

Comment: resource owner password flow is there ...but in okta web application which i use is not supporting but okta native app supports resouce owner password flow